# SSRS - Unnecessary column in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

Decided to just use an expression for LagerOrt column visibility:

```
=IIf(len(Fields!LagerOrt.Value)=0,True,False)
```

I'm using matrix to generate columns. This is my first time using matrices so I can't figure out why this empty extra column is showing up:

[image]

This is how my matrix is structured:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting empty value for "LagerOrt" among other values?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic seems like it, although I dont understand how. My query doesnt return any empty values. Decided to use an expression to save myself the time and hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use expression for 'LagerOrt' column visibility

```
=IIf(len(Fields!LagerOrt.Value)=0,True,False)
```